# sys.env.getOrElse Throw Exception

Tags: scala, environment-variables

I want the environment variable to be mandatory. If there is no environment variable then , throw exception . Throwing Exception in the else makes it non serializable, I need to use variable1 as a string value.

```
val variable1:String = sys.env.getOrElse("VAR1", "there is no default. It should throw Exception")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
val variable1:String = sys.env("VAR1")
```

It will throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: VAR1
```

`sys.env` is a `map`, so just calling with parenthesis will go to the [`apply`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0-M2/scala/collection/MapLike.html#apply(key:K):V) method:

```
def apply(key: K): V = get(key) match {
  case None => default(key)
  case Some(value) => value
}
```

And the [`default`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0-M2/scala/collection/MapLike.html#default(key:K):V) method is:

```
def default(key: K): V =
  throw new NoSuchElementException("key not found: " + key)
```

Answer (score 4):

`throw` yields an expression in Scala, and the second parameter of `getOrElse` is call-by-name, so you can just do this:

```
sys.env.getOrElse("VAR1", throw new Exception ("VAR1 must be set"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to throw a specific exception then I'd recommend `get()` and `fold()`.

```
val variable1:String = sys.env
                          .get("VAR1")
                          .fold(throw new Exception("BOOM!"))(identity)
```

Comment: what is (identity) after exception?

Comment: It's the "correct" way to do `x => x`, i.e. output is the unchanged input.